# What coordinate system is this data is in?

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a CSV with latitudes, longitudes, and place descriptions, I'm trying to figure out the CRS so I can reproject the data.

The data has no accessible documentation, and appears to be dumped out of an Oracle database.

Plotting the coordinates on a cartesian grid shows all of the United states and some places outside of it.

[image: map of points in the dataset]

What is the best way to figure the CRS out?

Here are a few examples from (juding by the FIPS codes) Brooklyn, Boston, and LA

```
Longitude, Latitude, State_Code, County_Code, Station_Location
73948800, 40725490, 36, 47, BTWN NORMAN AVE & DRIGGS AVE
71023639, 42424997, 25, 25, NORTHEAST EXPRESSWAY 
118442961, 34042668, 6, 37, N/O OLYMPIC BL; S/O JCT RTE 2
```

Answer (score 2):

In writing out this question I thought I'd look into one thing before I submitted.

Turns out these are just lat & lon but without decimal points and only positive

As such these coordinates appear to match the descriptions

```
Longitude, Latitude, State_Code, County_Code, Station_Location
-73.948800, 40.725490, 36, 47, BTWN NORMAN AVE & DRIGGS AVE
-71.023639, 42.424997, 25, 25, NORTHEAST EXPRESSWAY 
-118.442961, 34.042668, 6, 37, N/O OLYMPIC BL; S/O JCT RTE 2
```

Comment: to add the negative value and decimal places to the long and lat value you can multiply each individual value by 0.0000001